# How to add filter row widget in rally tree grid

Tags: rally, code-rally

I have a rally tree grid. I want a filter widget just  above the tree grid.
How we can add internal filter rally tree grid.

PFA screenshot.[filter widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uo0NA.png)

Thanks.

Comment: What did you try already?

Answer (score 0):

There is an example in the docs:

2.0 will give you the black popover style one: https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0/doc/#!/example/filterable-grid-board

2.1 will give you the newer advanced filter:
https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.1/doc/#!/example/filterable-grid-board

Both examples show using it with a board, but it should be straightforward to combine your existing code with the grid board component in the example- you just specify a gridConfig rather than a boardConfig.

Comment: thanks for reply.But the above solutions doesn not  allowing the custom fields in grid.How we can add custom column.